# An irreducible quadric hypersurface is rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Here quadric hypersurface just means it is generated by a polynomial with degree 2.

I can guess the idea is to project the hypersurface from a fixed point P, to some plane by drawing a line through P. And because the degree is 2, we can get one point on the plane? And the expression should be rational function.
But how to give a formal proof? That is to prove there exists a open set of the hypersurface that is isomorphic to a open set of some $A^m$.

Comment: @user26857 I am sorry. I just need time to understand thoroughly......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a point on the hypersurface $X$, say $P$, the projection from Fixed point $P$ is a rational map $\phi$ from $x\in X\setminus P$ to a hyperplane $P^{n-1}$of ambient space $P^n$. you know $\phi$ corresponds to the linear system $\{$ hyperplane  sections  of  $X$ passing through point P $\}$ with base point $P$. Then By Bezout theorem, away from $P$, $\phi$ is one to one. this map is finite morphism away from $P$. so it is homeomorphism. also check that it induces local isomorphism on sheaf structure i.e it is isomorphism of schemes. For this, you should work with specific equation of the hypersurface. it is a simple exercise.

Comment: Actually I am working in affine space, so does Bezout theorem still holds? Also, it is really hard for me to see the local isomorphism, why this is true?

Comment: as what I said, it is one to one and on to map on open subvariety as a set, so you don't need Worry about if it holds in affine case. And it does not hold by the way. As for isomorphism on opens, you need work specifically with equation of the hypersurface. for example in $P^2$ you will have $f: k[x] \rightarrow k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ so it is finite morphism, since it is integral extension, hence homeo as topological space, since it is one to one, affine morphism. As for sheaf structure it is local iso induced from the ring map. higher dimensional does not make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that the field is algebraically closed, since otherwise what you say is not true. Also, characteristic not 2, since quadrics are not so well behaved then. Given this, by completing square trick, you can reduce any quadric to the form $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_k^2$, for some $k$. If $k=1$, the quadric is non-reduced and for $k=2$, the quadric is reducible. So, assume that $k\geq 3$. Then we can write the above as $(x_1+\sqrt{-1}x_2)(x_1-\sqrt{-1}x_2)+x_3^2+\cdots+x_k^2$. Changing variables, this is same as $x_1x_2+x_3^2+\cdots$. Now, the open set $x_1\neq 0$ is given by $x_2=-\sum_{i\geq 3} x_i^2/x_1$ which is clearly the same as the open set $x_1\neq 0$ in the affine space with co-ordinates $x_1,x_3,\ldots$.